# How to disable value in select option when it already selected by another select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i have a simple form like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="">No Inventaris</label>
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" name="noInv" class="form-control" id="add_field" value="Klik untuk membuat text field baru"><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    $(function(){
        $('#add_field').click(function(){
            count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                '<strong >No Inv Barang Ke ' + count + '</strong><br />' 
                + '<select id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"  class="form-control no_inv"><?php $noInv = $this->modelku->select_inv() ?> <?php foreach($noInv->result() as $inv){ ?> <option value="<?php echo $inv->no_inv ?>"><?php echo $inv->no_inv ?></option><?php } ?></select><br>' );

        });
    });
    </script> 

</div>
```

When i click the button the field will regenerate select option, and the value is from database

select_inv function:

```
public function select_inv()
{
    $this->db->select("no_inv");
    $this->db->from('detail_barang');
    $this->db->where("kondisi = 'Ada' ");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

My Question: How can i disable value in select option when it already selected by another select option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if this is what you need.

i just created a sample dropdown and in my jquery i trigger the event change using the class of all select option then i will get the value of the select and id. after getting the value i check the val if it is empty or not if not empty then i will use the each function for all the select and get their id attribute so i can compare it with the id of the select and if their id is not the same then i will disabled the option with the same value of the selected dropdown.

and i use focus event for getting the previous value so i can reset whether the user change the value of the selected option.

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 
 $('body').on('click','#add_field',function(){
            count += 1;
            
            
            
            $('#container').append(
                '<strong >No Inv Barang Ke ' + count + '</strong><br />' 
                + '<select id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"  class="form-control no_inv select_alternate"> <option value="">select</option><option value="test1">test1</option><option value="test2">test2</option><option value="test3">test3</option></select><br></select><br>' );

        });

var count =0;
var previous;
var selectedData = [];
$('body').on('click','.select_alternate',function(){
      previous = this.value;
     
});


$('body').on('change','.select_alternate',function(){
    var val = this.value;
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    
    if(val != ''){
    
        $(".select_alternate").each(function(){
           var newID = $(this).attr('id');
           if(id != newID){
              $('#'+newID).children('option[value="' + val + '"]').prop('disabled',true);
               $('#'+newID).children('option[value="' + previous + '"]').prop('disabled',false);
               
               selectedData.splice($.inArray(val, selectedData),1);
           }else{
              selectedData.push(val);
           
           }
        
        });

        
    }else{

      $(".select_alternate").each(function(){
           var newID = $(this).attr('id');
           if(id != newID){
              $('#'+newID).children('option[value="' + previous + '"]').prop('disabled',false);
              
           }
        
        });
    
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="">No Inventaris</label>
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" name="noInv" class="form-control" id="add_field" value="Klik untuk membuat text field baru"><br>
   
</div>
```

Comment: i didnt put any code for the add new select option button because our main goal here is just the disabled and enabled option in other select input

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but your select option is made manually, the value of the select option does not take from the database. can u make it with my original html pls?

Comment: my script above is: when i click the button, select option will automatically created and the value of select option is from database. So when i click the button 2x, 2 select option will automatically created, and etc

Comment: yeah i just remove that button for example purpose only. you can try it with the button. do you want me to add the code for the button add select input?

Comment: check  my edit i have created an array here naming selectedData i will feed this array variable with the selected value of the input then you can add a condition in the add field event to instantly disable the new appended inputs. you can use it in your foreach statement before appending an option in the select field check it if the selectedData contains the field then put disable in the option and thats it

Comment: @masdap No problem :)